# Deedle frame to R

Tags: r, f#, dataframe, deedle

I am trying to put some code to work.
I am using [rinterop](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/rinterop.html) as a reference.

I have a `Frame<DateTime,string>` which I try to send over to R using

```ml
let frame = 
    let aSerie = 
        Series.ofObservations 
            [ DateTime(2013,1,1) => 10.0
              DateTime(2013,1,4) => 20.0
              DateTime(2013,1,8) => 30.0 ] 
    Frame(["Hello"], [aSerie])
R.as_data_frame(frame)
```

which gives the following:

> System.Exception: No converter registered for type
>   Deedle.Series`2[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],

I also tried the following example:

```ml
let rnd = Random()
let ts = 
  [ for i in 0.0 .. 100.0 -> 
      DateTime.Today.AddHours(i), rnd.NextDouble() ] 
  |> series
R.as_zoo(ts)
```

which result in the same kind of error:

> System.Exception: No converter registered for type
>   Deedle.Series`2[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Double,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] or any of its base types

My ultimate goal is to chart Deedle frames, with `DateTime` as row keys using R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a bug in the installation script in FsLab - can you please check that the files `Deedle.dll` and `Deedle.RProvider.Plugin.dll` (hidden somewhere in the `packages` folder) were copied to the directory where `RProvider.dll` lives (that is `packages\RProvider.1.0.5\lib`).

If no, does copying the files there resolve the issue? (Assuming the files are not there and copying them to the directory solves the problem, this looks like a bug in our installation script for FsLab.)

Comment: Hi, yes. that fixed the problem. Thanks! Btw, would you have some example code on how to use ggplot with deedle frames? Thanks.