# 'No converter registered for type Deedle.Frame' using F# R type provider and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, f#, deedle

I'm working on my first attempt to use R's GGPlot2 via the F# R type provider.

Here's my code:

```
let (++) (plot1:RDotNet.SymbolicExpression) (plot2:RDotNet.SymbolicExpression) = 
    R.``+``(plot1, plot2) 

let ChartGgPlot2 (prices : Prices) =
    try
        let fileName = makeFile ".png"
        let priceSeries = prices.Prices |> Seq.map (fun p -> p.Date, p.Close) |> series
        let dataFrame = Deedle.Frame.ofRecords priceSeries

        R.png(filename=fileName, height=200, width=300, bg="white") |> ignore
        R.ggplot(
            namedParams[
                "data", box dataFrame; 
                "mapping", box (
                    R.aes__string(x="Date", y="Close"))])
        ++ R.geom__point() |> ignore
        R.dev_off() |> ignore
        fileName |> Choice.succeed
    with
    | e -> Choice.fail e.Message
```

`p.Date` is a `System.DateTime` and `p.Close` is a double.

At runtime I get this exception at the point of calling `R.ggplot`:

> No converter registered for type Deedle.Frame`2[[System.DateTime,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] or
>   any of its base types

I've tried the solution suggested suggested here (copying two DLLs): [Deedle frame to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425017/deedle-frame-to-r) but that didn't make a difference.

I should also say that my usage of `series` and `Frame.ofRecords` is pretty much guesswork at this point.

Many thanks.

Edit:

- It's a compiled .NET 4.6 project with RProvider (1.1.20) and Deedle.RPlugin (1.2.5) added via Nuget.
- ggplot2 works correctly from RGui.

Comment: How are you referencing R provider & Deedle? Is this in a script file?

Comment: It's in a compiled project with the R provider and Deedle nuget-ed in.  Using plain old R.plot works fine.

Comment: thanks. can you also show what you are opening?

Comment: Convertors for Deedle are implemented in `Deedle.RPlugin` and R provider needs to discover the DLL. It uses "ProbingLocations" from app.config (https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/FSharpRProvider/blob/master/src/RProvider/app.config) which has a default value pointing to "other nuget packages", which works in the scripting scenario, but I'm not sure about "compiled" scenario. Can you try modifying probing locations in `RProvider.Server.exe` config to point to the current directory? (Or directory with the Deedle.RPlugin files?)

Answer (score 2):

Tomas's comment about config files and probing locations wasn't the answer - but it clued me in to what actually was the answer.

I needed to use Nuget to add references to Deedle.RPlugin, not only to the assembly that was doing the R calls to render a chart, but also to my 'main' assembly that references the charting assembly.

I don't know if this is an inherent limitation in the way the build system interacts with the type provider.  But for now I'm very happy to have a workaround.

(For teaching purposes it would be great to know if there could be a long term fix.)

Huge thanks to those that replied.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible something is off with your FSLab and/or Rprovider install. This for example should work:

```
#load @"..\..\FSLAB\packages\FsLab\FsLab.fsx"
open System
open Deedle
open FSharp.Charting
open System
open RDotNet
open RProvider
open RProvider.graphics
open RProvider.stats 
open RProvider.datasets 
open RProvider.ggplot2

type DtPx = {
    Dt:System.DateTime
    Px:float
}

let rnd = System.Random()
let nextPx() = rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5
let nextDay i = DateTime.Today.AddDays(float i)

let data = List.init 100 (fun i -> {Dt=nextDay i;Px = nextPx()})
let df = Frame.ofRecords data

let mtc = R.mtcars.GetValue<Frame<string, string>>()
let (++) (plot1:RDotNet.SymbolicExpression) (plot2:RDotNet.SymbolicExpression) = 
    R.``+``(plot1, plot2)


R.ggplot(
    namedParams[
        "data", box mtc; 
        "mapping", box (
            R.aes__string(x="disp", y="drat"))])
++ R.geom__point()

R.ggplot(
            namedParams[
                "data", box df; 
                "mapping", box (
                    R.aes__string(x="Dt", y="Px"))])
++ R.geom__point()
```

You can use this in an fsx file, but also in a compiled .exe to save the output to png. In that case you will have to reference DynamicInterop, RDotNet, Rprovider, etc as well.

[image: Random Px]

**References:**

[image: Updated References]

This is for an empty project nugetting Deedle and RProvider related packages.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try adding that code to the existing context to see if that works.

Comment: Same problem with the above code when merged into mine - i.e. "No converter registered..."

Comment: In that case I suspect maybe it's some sort of installation issue. Just in case I will show the actual references in a screenshot. Can you run this is fsx at least?

Comment: Yes, as it happens I literally just tried that. I had to add a ggsave as R.png was writing a blank image.  But certainly didn't get the error.

Checking through the references now, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I am missing RProvider.Runtime.dll and RProvider.DesignTime.dll.  I've got a funny feeling I've had to add the equivalents manually, in other type provider based projects.  Trying that.

Comment: Correction - it was onlyl RProvider.DesignTime.dll reference that was missing.  Added that and checked that RunTime and DesignTime both had copy local set to true.  Same problem.

Comment: it's going to be difficult to troubleshoot. Maybe try starting a totally new solution. I tried it in a blank solution, nugetting RDotnet, Rprovider, Deedle, Deedle Rplugin, etc. and on my end it works. I will update the screenshot with a cleaner one.

Comment: Clean solution seems like the way to go.  This one has a chequered history.  I'll update here when tried.  Thanks!